# Telerik reporting: problem getting DataSource to be recognized at design time

Tags: datasource, design-time, telerik-reporting

I am new to Telerik reporting. I have been trying to follow this [KB article](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/designing-reports/using-data-source-with-parameters-in-telerik-reporting.aspx), more or less.

The approach described there bypasses the Wizard. I need to bypass the Wizard because the database is SQL Server 2000 and the Wizard demands 2005 or later.

I drag and drop a sqlDataAdapter to the report from the Toolbox. The adapter is configured in the report's constructor.

When I add a text field to my report and go to its properties page and click on the ellipsis [...] button for Value and the click "Fields" in the lower left section of the dialog, the pane to the right says "No Data Source".

How to get the datasource to be recognized at design-time? What am I missing? Thanks

```
namespace EventsReportingClassLibrary
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using Telerik.Reporting;
    using Telerik.Reporting.Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Report1.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Report1 : Telerik.Reporting.Report
    {

        private SqlConnection CNN;

        private SqlDataAdapter DA
        {
            get { return sqlDataAdapter1;  //  dropped from the toolbox onto report}
        }

        private string ConnectionString 
         {
                get { return "server=server5\\SQL2K;Initial Catalog=foo;User Id=foo2;Password=foo3;Pooling=yes"; }   
         }

        public Report1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();


           CNN = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);          
           DA.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from myView",CNN);
            DA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            this.DataSource = DA;
        }

        private void Report1_NeedDataSource(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
          // fires at run-time if datasource of this report is null

        }


    }

}
```